# Working on Ubuntu from Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote Desktop for Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/44536/remote-desktop-for-ubuntu)

First, I have to say that I have no experience in working with Ubuntu or any other Unix like distributions. I have two computers and I wish to have the following setup and working scenario.

In one computer I need to have Ubuntu and to connect to it from a Windows station using my LAN.

Can you recommend a tutorial (link, video, anything)?

Comment: Duplicate of many, like "Remote Desktop for Ubuntu" at http://superuser.com/questions/44536/remote-desktop-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

I'll probably start by deciding if i want to use the remote system in cli or gui.

[putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is defacto 'standard' ssh client for windows- it handles only cli so is often used with xming

While its a whole load heavier, i prefer [mobaxterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/en/) - it has x server support baked in (you can remote into a whole gui session), a proper unix style terminal on windows (so you connect to a system with ssh  and such). It also lets you get used to the unix style cli to an extent - so its a nice intermediate between handholding in terms of getting started, and giving you the chance to learn the knowledge of to use linux tools.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different solutions

1. [Share your Ubuntu Desktop Using Remote Desktop](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/share-your-ubuntu-desktop-using-remote-desktop.html)
2. [Howto Easily run an Xserver under Windows](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=225898)
3. [Use Synergy to share a single mouse and keyboard between multiple computers](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) client/server pair. VNC, in case you're not sure about what it is, is a remote desktop protocol. If you don't know what *that* is - it's a way of viewing and controlling the screen of a system through another system. I avoided using "computer" because you can use remote desktop software to connect to a virtual PC.

[Wikipedia's list of remote desktop clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) is quite confusing, so for a basic list of VNC software you can have a look [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=vnc). It lists RealVNC, TightVNC and UltraVNC on the first page, which are quite well known VNC software.